# Date validation in MM/DD/YYYY format in excel column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to validate an excel column having date field of DD/MM/YYYY format.It's an existing column , I want to color/differentiate cells having wrong values.

1. It should always be in DD/MM/YYYY format.
2. It should validate data also. like 29/02/2017 should mark as wrong entry. similarly 31/04/2018 is wrong entry.

I don't know if there is any easy way of validation of both structure and data in excel for already defined excel fields. Any help?

Comment: I am a little confused by point number 1 and 2. You say that the format should always be in DD/MM/YYYY, but then in point two you say that 29/02/2017 should be marked as a wrong entry.

Comment: @IrwinAllen13, that's possibly because it aint real dates ;)

Comment: HAHAHA - Wow i missed that. I am sorry it has been a long morning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dates in range A2:A10 then select the first cell, A2. From the Home tab, use Conditional Formatting, Manage Rules, New Rule. Under use formula enter `=ISERR(DAY(A2))`. Use Format to set the cell formatting, then select OK. Then in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager, modify the range under Applies to $A2:$A10. This will highlight all the none dates.

Comment: `=IF(CELL("format", A1)=D4` will check if dateformat is actually `dd/mm/yyyy`. Might you wish to include that in your answer.

Comment: That is a partial formula and when finished would check for m/d/yy h:mm or mm/dd/yy. D1 is dd/mm/yyy. `=IF(CELL("format", A2)="D1",TRUE)` would, indeed, give a response on a correct date format.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of accomplishing this task.

The first method would be to do conditional formatting as you have requested with this formula.

`=IF(AND(NOT(ISERR(DAY(A2))), CELL("Format", A2)="D1"),TRUE, FALSE)`

The second method could be used, but doesn't require the use of conditional formatting instead it using Data Validations. Data Validations won't change the color of a cell, but it will prevent you from inserting a invalid date.

1. Format the Cell 'Number' to a category type of 'Custom' and then the type should read - 'dd/mm/yyyy'
2. Now, add 'Data Validation' to the cells in question. The 'Data Validation' should be the following

Allow: 'Date'
Data: 'greater than'
Start Date: '01/01/1900'

Once you have done this, all of the dates will still need to be TYPED as 'mm/dd/yyyy' but as soon as your press 'enter' then the format will change it over to 'dd/mm/yyyy'